# Does Datastore support bulk updates?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I've combed through GC DataStore documentation, but I haven't found anything useful around bulk updating documents. Does anyone have best practice around bulk updates in DataStore? Is that even a valid use case for DataStore? (I'm thinking something along the lines of MongoDB Bulk.find.update or db.Collection.bulkWrite)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [projects.commit](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/projects/commit) API call to write multiple changes at once. Most client libraries have a way to do this, for example in python use [`put_multi`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/datastore/client.html#google.cloud.datastore.client.Client.put_multi).

In C# the [`DatastoreDb.Insert` method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreDb.html#Google_Cloud_Datastore_V1_DatastoreDb_Insert_Google_Cloud_Datastore_V1_Entity___) has an overload for adding multiple entities at once.

If this is a one-off, consider using [`gcloud`'s import function](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#importing_entities).

Comment: Thanks David... this isn't a one-off, we're looking to bake this functionality into a connector we're building for Datastore, and we're using the c# client. Doesn't look like this library has any nice 'multi' wrappers like the python lib, but if I missed something, let me know.

Comment: In C# the [`DatastoreDb.Insert` method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1/api/Google.Cloud.Datastore.V1.DatastoreDb.html#Google_Cloud_Datastore_V1_DatastoreDb_Insert_Google_Cloud_Datastore_V1_Entity___) has an overload for adding multiple entities at once.